# Who maintains gpu-manager?

Tags: drivers, kernel, xorg, video, gpu-driver

gpu-manager reporting what seems to be a problem. No documentation. No apparent home. Who maintains it? How do you get in touch to report problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is part of ubuntu-drivers-common

If you search for this package you will find

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-drivers-common

And on that page is information of filing bug reports and maintainers

Maintainer:

Ubuntu Core Developers (Mail Archive)
Please consider filing a bug or asking a question via Launchpad before contacting the maintainer directly.

Original Maintainer (usually from Debian):

Ubuntu Developers (Mail Archive)
It should generally not be necessary for users to contact the original maintainer.

email ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com

See also [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug/5126#5126)